# What is causing this TypeError when trying to insert data into a Postgres DB via a Lambda Function?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, lambda

I'm using node 16.17.0, the default lambda aws-sdk for Nodejs, and "pg": "^8.7.3".

After using the s3.getObject(params).promise(), I'm able to store the contents of a JSON file (in the screenshot), and from there, I have a SQL statement to insert the retrieved data into the confirmed correct columns within the database (I've used dummmy data before to insert 5000 rows). However, with the following code, I'm getting a type error as shown in the description. I have absolutely no idea how to solve this "promise" issue. I've tried creating my own promise and using a .then() to insert data to no avail. I'm wondering could this be a versioning issue more than anything? This is the only get-object method that works in my environment. I've gotten the getObject(params, (err, data)) method to work on my personal machine a few times, but that solution simply won't work in this case. I've tried googling the solution and I'm not finding anyone who has seen this error

[JSON data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4XXn.png)

Every variation of creating a new Promise manually ends up with this error. Also, that JSON.stringify was only to see if maybe the data wasn't in string format, but neither keeping nor removing that parsing works.

```
const insertLegacyData = async (event, _context, _callback) => {
    const queries = require("../Utility/queries");
    const helper = require("../Utility/helper");
    const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    const s3 = new AWS.S3();
    const { Pool } = require("pg");
    try {

        var params = {
            Bucket: "bucketName",
            Key: "theData.json"
        };

        var results = await s3.getObject(params).promise();
        results = JSON.parse(results.Body).results[0]['items'];
        results = JSON.stringify(results.results[0]['items']);

        let token = helper.getToken(); 
        var pool = new Pool(helper.getPool(token));

        pool.query('TRUNCATE TABLE "fumes_schema"."consumption"', (err, res) => {
            if (err) throw err;
        });

        for (let i = 0; i < 5923; i++) {
            console.log(`Iteration: ${i}`);
            pool.query('INSERT INTO "schema"."theTable"(seq_nbr, origination, destination, aircraft_type, month_12_gallons, month_12_flights, month_12_minutes, month_11_gallons, month_11_flights, month_11_minutes, month_10_gallons, month_10_flights, month_10_minutes, month_09_gallons, month_09_flights, month_09_minutes, month_08_gallons, month_08_flights, month_08_minutes, month_07_gallons, month_07_flights, month_07_minutes, month_06_gallons, month_06_flights, month_06_minutes, month_05_gallons, month_05_flights, month_05_minutes, month_04_gallons, month_04_flights, month_04_minutes, month_03_gallons, month_03_flights, month_03_minutes, month_02_gallons, month_02_flights, month_02_minutes, month_01_gallons, month_01_flights, month_01_minutes) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18, $19, $20, $21, $22, $23, $24, $25, $26, $27, $28, $29, $30, $31, $32, $33, $34, $35, $36, $37, $38, $39, $40);', [(i + 1), [results[i]["depature_arpt_cd"], results[i]["arr_arpt_cd"], results[i]["ac_typ_cd"], results[i]["m12gal"], results[i]["m12cnt"], results[i]["m12_duration_in_minutes"], results[i]["m11gal"], results[i]["m11cnt"], results[i]["m11_duration_in_minutes"], results[i]["m10gal"], results[i]["m10cnt"], results[i]["m10_duration_in_minutes"], results[i]["m9gal"], results[i]["m9cnt"], results[i]["m9_duration_in_minutes"], results[i]["m8gal"], results[i]["m8cnt"], results[i]["m8_duration_in_minutes"], results[i]["m7gal"], results[i]["m7cnt"], results[i]["m7_duration_in_minutes"], results[i]["m6gal"], results[i]["m6cnt"], results[i]["m6_duration_in_minutes"], results[i]["m5gal"], results[i]["m5cnt"], results[i]["m5_duration_in_minutes"], results[i]["m4gal"], results[i]["m4cnt"], results[i]["m4_duration_in_minutes"], results[i]["m3gal"], results[i]["m3cnt"], results[i]["m3_duration_in_minutes"], results[i]["m2gal"], results[i]["m2cnt"], results[i]["m2_duration_in_minutes"], results[i]["m1gal"], results[i]["m1cnt"], results[i]["m1_duration_in_minutes"]]]);
        };
            
        await pool.end();
    
        response = helper.createSuccessResponse('Successful DB truncation & legacy data insertion', 'legacyData', 'Legacy Data Insertion', {});
        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify(response)
        };
    } catch (err) {
        response = helper.createErrorResponse(`${err}`, 'legacyData', 'Legacy Data Insertion', {});
        return {
            statusCode: 500,
            body: JSON.stringify(response)
        };
    }
};
```

```
{
    "errorType": "TypeError",
    "errorMessage": "The \"string\" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or ArrayBuffer. Received an instance of Promise",
    "code": "ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE",
    "stack": [
        "TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The \"string\" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or ArrayBuffer. Received an instance of Promise",
        "    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)",
        "    at Function.byteLength (node:buffer:735:11)",
        "    at Writer.addCString (/var/task/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/buffer-writer.js:42:30)",
        "    at Object.password (/var/task/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/serializer.js:25:19)",
        "    at Connection.password (/var/task/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:131:26)",
        "    at /var/task/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:238:23",
        "    at Client._checkPgPass (/var/task/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:225:7)",
        "    at Client._handleAuthCleartextPassword (/var/task/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:237:10)",
        "    at Connection.emit (node:events:527:28)",
        "    at Connection.emit (node:domain:475:12)"
    ]
}
```

EDIT: The getToken and getPool code:

```js
const getToken = async () => {
    const signer = new AWS.RDS.Signer({
        region: process.env.AWS_REGION ? process.env.AWS_REGION : '',
        hostname: process.env.Fumes_RDS_HOST ? process.env.Fumes_RDS_HOST : '',
        port: Number(process.env.Fumes_RDS_PORT),
        username: process.env.Fumes_RDS_USER ? process.env.Fumes_RDS_USER : ''
    });
    return await signer.getAuthToken({ username: process.env.Fumes_RDS_USER ? process.env.Fumes_RDS_USER : '' });
}

function getPool(token) {
    return {
        user: process.env.Fumes_RDS_USER ? process.env.Fumes_RDS_USER : '',
        host: process.env.Fumes_RDS_HOST ? process.env.Fumes_RDS_HOST : '',
        database: process.env.Fumes_RDS_DB ? process.env.Fumes_RDS_DB : '',
        password: token,
        port: Number(process.env.Fumes_RDS_PORT),
        ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false },
        /* eslint-disable */
        authSwitchHandler: function ({ _pluginName, _pluginData }, _cb) {
            /* eslint-enable */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Given this is happening in `Connection.password`, it seems that `helper.getPool(token)` returns a promise (or an object containing promises) instead of the pool options object. Please post that code

Comment: You should not be using a pool at all here, but rather a single connection (`Client`). And you should absolutely `await` each `.query()` that you're making.

Comment: Doing both `results = JSON.parse(results.Body).results[0]['items'];` and `results = JSON.stringify(results.results[0]['items']);` doesn't look right

Comment: @Bergi Thank you, I've changed the pool to a client and used await for each insert. The code for the getToken (for that token param) and the getPool code are in the description now

Comment: You missed to `await` the `helper.getToken();` promise

Comment: @Bergi forgot to respond, but you solved it! Thank you again, it helped be get a better understanding of async/await in general